# Deprecated functions in mongoose using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

mongoose has many depreciated functions, such as `findByIdAndUpdate`. Here's a list of all the deprecated functions: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options

Am I supposed be using the deprecated functions, and silent them using the way explained in that linked page, or is there another way of performing the deprecated functions?

I looked all over, and it seemed like all websites were saying to silent the warnings, and there aren't any alternatives. What's the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Mongoose's `findByIdAndUpdate` [hasn't been deprecated](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6880#issuecomment-435621543). The warning is for the method that Mongoose is using from the underlying driver – [`Collection.findAndModify()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#findAndModify). – The `useFindAndModify` option doesn't simply silence the warning; it avoids using the deprecated method from the driver. It's explained better in [the docs page for Deprecations](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#-findandmodify-).

Comment: Well said!!! Please make this into an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose hasn't deprecated its own method, `Model.findByIdAndUpdate()`. The warnings are from it in turn using a method from the underlying MongoDB driver – [`Collection.findAndModify()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#findAndModify).

> **Deprecated**
>
> - use `findOneAndUpdate`, `findOneAndReplace` or `findOneAndDelete` instead

The `useFindAndModify` option is better explained in [another docs page on Deprecations](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#-findandmodify-). But, the option doesn't just silence the warning. It configures Mongoose to avoid using `findAndModify()` so the warning doesn't need to be given.

Granted, in the same docs page, Mongoose does emphasize the need to test any setting changes:

> Mongoose provides options to work around these deprecation warnings, but you need to test whether these options cause any problems for your application.

Though, for my own take, when using a version of the MongoDB native driver that produces the warning (apparently 2.0+), it's probably better to change the option and avoid using `findAndModify()`.